# TextView error in the xml file

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with long text, but its line spacing is not showing properly in some devices.

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bits_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/yellowfacesnooze"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPathBold"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Praesent pretium nulla sit amet mollis consectetur. Aenean sed felis in ante dictum facilisis. Etiam suscipit lorem sed nisl interdum, ac vulputate tortor tempor."
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the first image the display looks good, while the second one is improper.Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

[Image from the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCbX.png)

[Image from the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF8Ij.png)

Comment: Add string in string.xml.

Comment: try to change the layout_height of parent linearlayout from 150dp to match_parent, just to check is it same in both the cases

Comment: Change layout height to wrap_content in textView as well as linearlayout.

Comment: `orientation` of both layouts must be same, first change it.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki i try with match_parent but the layout is compressed and  with wrap_content gives the same error with 150dp on the layout height.

Comment: Sorry I miss a part of code I will edit the code, sorry is my first time on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to the font you are using, along with the layout height you are using, I updated your XML to the best practice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPathBold"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Praesent pretium nulla sit amet mollis consectetur. Aenean sed felis in ante dictum facilisis. Etiam suscipit lorem sed nisl interdum, ac vulputate tortor tempor."
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I did was that I made the outer layout height as wrap content and updated its orientation, removed the inner Linear layout as it is useless, and finally added the **includeFontPadding** attribute with the false value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use parent `LinearLayout` height as `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="150dp"`
2. Use `android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"` to give extra space between lines `(if needs)`

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPathBold"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:text="Praesent pretium nulla sit amet mollis consectetur. Aenean sed felis in ante dictum facilisis. Etiam suscipit lorem sed nisl interdum, ac vulputate tortor tempor."
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```